# Angular2: Extend RouterOutlet in new release rc6 for activate method

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using angular2 rc6 and wouldn't mind to use the latest announced release.
I am trying to implement the router outlet to provide access to only authenticated users.

I have this block of code which works in previous release.

**Old Code:**

```js
import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class AuthCheck extends RouterOutlet {
    publicRoutes: any;
    private parentRouter: Router;
    
    constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader, _parentRouter: Router,
    @Attribute('name')nameAttr:string) {
        super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);
        
        this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
        this.publicRoutes = {
            'login': true
        };
    }
    
    activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
        let url = instruction.urlPath;
        
        if(!this.publicRoutes[url] && !localStorage.getItem('auth_key')){
            this.parentRouter.navigateByUrl('/login');
        }
        
        return super.activate(instruction);
    }
}
```

I am trying to change the code to work in rc 6, but need some help to implement the "activate" method to provide the same behavior:

**Changed Code:**

```js
//import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, RouterOutletMap, ActivatedRoute, } from '@angular/router';

import {
    Component, Directive, ComponentMetadata, Input, ReflectiveInjector,
    ViewContainerRef, Compiler, NgModule, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injector, ResolvedReflectiveProvider
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class AuthCheck extends RouterOutlet {
    publicRoutes: any;
    private parentRouter: RouterOutletMap;

    constructor(_parentOutletMap: RouterOutletMap, _location: ViewContainerRef, _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
            name: string)
    //constructor(_elementRef: ViewContainerRef, _loader: any, _parentRouter: Router,
    //    @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string)
    {
        super(_parentOutletMap, _location, _resolver, name);

        this.parentRouter = _parentOutletMap;
        this.publicRoutes = {
            'login': true
        };
    }

    activate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, loadedResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, loadedInjector: Injector, providers: ResolvedReflectiveProvider[], outletMap: RouterOutletMap) {
        //implementation

    }

    //activate(instruction: any) {
    //    let url = instruction.urlPath;

    //    if (!this.publicRoutes[url] && !localStorage.getItem('auth_key')) {
    //        this.parentRouter.registerOutlet.('/login');
    //    }

    //    return super.activate(instruction);
    //}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that worked? the answer seems to be code for something else and not your code.

Comment: The accepted answer uses the "canActivate" property of a route, which does the job the enquirer wanted to solve. But I am interested if there is a solution using the "activate" method for other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this type of solution in angular 2 rc7. Hope, this helps you as well.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    if (state.url !== '/login' && !this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Also my LoginService is:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { IMenu } from '../interfaces/menu';
import { AppSettings } from '../AppSettings';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
    private _baseUrl:string = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT;
    private _loggedIn = false;

    constructor(private _http : Http, private  _router : Router){
        this._loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token') 
        && !!localStorage.getItem('role')
        && !!localStorage.getItem('menu')
    }


    //Post function to send username and password to authorize in the server
    login(Username:string, Password:string) : Observable<IMenu[]>{
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(Username + ":" + Password)); 
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return this._http.post(this._baseUrl+"auth/login", " " , {headers: headers}  ).delay(2000).
            map((response: Response) => {
                <IMenu[]>response.json();
                localStorage.setItem("menu",JSON.stringify(<IMenu[]>response.json()));
                localStorage.setItem("auth_token", response.headers.get("Token"));
                localStorage.setItem("role", response.headers.get("Role"));
            }).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem("auth_token");
        localStorage.removeItem("menu");
        localStorage.removeItem("role");
        this._router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }

    isLoggedIn() {
        return this._loggedIn;
    }

    private handleError(error: Response){
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error!');
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps you...